# What are the last six digits of the rails migration file's naming convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

E.g. 20170430193631_create_articles.rb

The first eight are yyyymmdd, but what are the last six digits?

I am following along with the [rails tutorial for rails 4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/getting_started.html#creating-the-article-model). On April 30, 2017, just prior to 4pm EST  I invoked `rails g model Article title:string text:text` and the "...193631..." part of the name doesn't appear to be related to the time of day. Is this just a random number, or is there something more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hour, minute, second (HHMMSS) in UTC timezone.

Comment: I guess it was a little more than "just prior" to 4pm EST :) Thanks!